# Jumping to a Ruby bang method using Ctags in Vim

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags

I'm having a problem with jumping to a Ruby bang method using Exhuberant Ctags. I have searched for others having a similar problem and am unable to find anything. An example of the problem can be shown using the following small Ruby class:

```rb
class Hello
  def start
    method!
  end

  def method
    # Blah
  end

  def method!
    # Blah
  end
end
```

When `ctags -R .` is run on this file the resulting `tags` file contains the following 2 lines demonstrating that both methods are discovered at generation:

```
method  test.rb /^  def method$/;"  f   class:Hello
method! test.rb /^  def method!$/;" f   class:Hello
```

However, if I place my cursor on the call to `method!` on line 3 and press `^]` then the cursor jumps to the `method` definition rather than to the correct bang version. It seems as if the exclamation mark is not being included in the identifier that is searched for.

Is there a way to fix this so the correct method is jumped to?

Comment: ^] correctly jumps to the right method in my version of vim. What version of vim and ctags are you using? I do have vim-ruby and matchit installed and enabled. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm using MacVim Snapshot 63 which is built on Vim 7.3. I too have both of those plugins. The problem still persists even if I start vim with no configuration (`mvim -u NONE`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this is super-old, but I ran into the same thing in both Vim 8.0 and Neovim. If I enter `:tag mymethod!` from vim's command-line, it finds the relevant tag, but if I try **`<C-]>`** with my cursor on the method name, it errors `E426: tag not found: mymethod` (note the lack of `!` in the name it searched for).

You can fix this by adding `!` to the list of characters recognized as keyword characters in Ruby syntax:

```
:set iskeyword+=!
```

You could add this to `~/.vim/after/syntax/ruby.vim` to apply it in any Ruby file you open. I haven't tested this though, so can't say whether it will adversely affect anything else. I know it will change word jumping behavior. **`w`** will, for instance, treat the `!` as part of the "small" word.

On second thought, it will definitely mishandle things like `!some_test`. If you were to hit **`<C-]>`** with the cursor anywhere in there, it would search for a method named `!some_test`, which is definitely not what you want. A better solution would be to write a wrapper function around the tag lookup for Ruby files. I'm actually working on something for that, so I'll post when I have something that presentable.

*Update*: I found a surprisingly simple workaround:

```
nnoremap <buffer><silent> <C-]> :tag <C-R><C-W><CR>
```

For some reason, the behavior of **`<C-R><C-W>`** in command-line mode differs from that of `expand('<cword>')`, and arguably from the documentation. Even though `!` is not an `'iskeyword'` character, and `expand('<cword>')` results in `mymethod`, **`<C-R><C-W>`** results in `mymethod!`. The same applies to `is_this_your_method?`. You could apply this workaround by putting the following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer><silent>  <C-]> :tag     <C-R><C-W><CR>
nnoremap <buffer><silent>     g] :tselect <C-R><C-W><CR>
nnoremap <buffer><silent> g<C-]> :tjump   <C-R><C-W><CR>
```

*Update 2*

It turns out the special behavior of `<C-R><C-W>` was provided by vim-ruby (and included in Vim's runtime files by default). That script customizes `<C-R><C-W>` and also adds a `<Plug><cword>` mapping to correctly identify the Ruby cursor identifier. I only ran into the mishandling of `!` because I had inadvertently clobbered the mappings already provided by vim-ruby when adding what I find to be more a comfortable keybinding:

```
nnoremap <C-.> <C-]>
```

If I'd done `nmap` instead, vim-ruby's mapping could have done its job. Alternatively, you could leverage what vim-ruby provides by doing (in a ruby ftplugin file):

```
nnoremap <buffer><silent>  <C-]> :<C-U>exe v:count1."tag <Plug><cword>"<CR>
nnoremap <buffer><silent>     g] :<C-U>tselect <Plug><cword><CR>
nnoremap <buffer><silent> g<C-]> :<C-U>tjump   <Plug><cword><CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `:tag`:

```
  :tag method!
```

Or visual mode - if you highlight any text (with **v** + movement) before you hit **^]**, it will use the highlighted text as the tag instead of trying to find an 'identifier' under the cursor.  So if your cursor is on the `m` in `method!`, then

```
   vE^]
```

should do the trick.  If your cursor is elsewhere in the word, then hit `b` first.

Comment: I've remapped `^]` to `viW^]` for now, thank you! However, some of the semantics of this operation will have changed so I'm not sure this solution is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I was using MacVim snapshot 63 at the time I posted this question. I'm now using snapshot 72 and the problem has gone. The only advice I can give here is to upgrade the version of Vim that you are using.

Comment: Also check the version of `ctags` you're using.  Older versions - like the no-version-numbered one that still ships with Xcode as of 6.1 - won't even generate tags for bang methods for vim to reference.  I used Homebrew to install Exuberant Ctags 5.8 and regenerated the tags files; now vim navigates to bang (and question-mark) methods just fine.